# Using output keyword to get last inserted records in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, crud

I have [**this tool**](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) (SSMS Tools Pack ) which generates CRUD sp's for a specific table

But ive look at the "insert" code

```
/*1*/   CREATE PROC [dbo].[usp_EServices_ME_Country_InfoInsert] 
/*2*/       @MasterEntityID int,
/*3*/       ...
/*4*/   AS 
/*5*/       SET NOCOUNT ON 
/*6*/       SET XACT_ABORT ON  
/*7*/       
/*8*/       BEGIN TRAN
/*9*/       
/*10*/      INSERT INTO [dbo].[EServices_ME_Country_Info] ([MasterEntityID],...)
/*11*/      SELECT @MasterEntityID, ...
/*12*/      
/*13*/      -- Begin Return Select <- do not remove
/*14*/      SELECT [ID], [MasterEntityID],...
/*15*/      FROM   [dbo].[EServices_ME_Country_Info]
/*16*/      WHERE  [ID] = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
/*17*/      -- End Return Select <- do not remove
/*18*/                  
/*19*/      COMMIT
/*20*/   GO
```

My Question is about line #14 -- Could They/I use the `output` keyword ? and if so , would the `output` would return **all** the inserted records ? ( if there's >1 inserted records at line #11 )

Comment: Do you mean the `OUTPUT` clause?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ooops. yes. sorry. editing (too much c#)

Comment: OUTPUT clause can be used only in UPDATE, INSERT, MERGE and DELETE statements. AND it returns output for all affected rows. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Comment: @Igor so how does my line #10 should look like ? mus i use `INTO` ?  ( and would it include the scope_idents ? and please consider posting it as an asnwer.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I added an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting question! Based on the info on the `OUTPUT` clause [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx), I would think you could change this:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EServices_ME_Country_Info] ([MasterEntityID],...)
SELECT @MasterEntityID, ...

-- Begin Return Select <- do not remove
SELECT [ID], [MasterEntityID],...
FROM   [dbo].[EServices_ME_Country_Info]
WHERE  [ID] = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
-- End Return Select <- do not remove
```

to this:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EServices_ME_Country_Info] ([MasterEntityID],...)
OUTPUT INSERTED.MasterEntityID, ...
SELECT @MasterEntityID, ...
```

with the same result. This is just theory for now, I'll go test this and follow up.

**Follow up:**

My `OUTPUT` clause was not correct, you have to use `OUTPUT` right after the `INSERT` clause. Edited that in the query above. I used the following code to test this:

```
-- Create a test table
CREATE TABLE TestTable (
    ID INT IDENTITY
    ,TestV1 INT
    ,TestV2 INT
    ,TestV3 INT
);
GO

-- Example sp with the 'old' method using SCOPE_IDENTITY()
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_InsertFirstMethod
(
    @v1 INT
    ,@v2 INT
    ,@v3 INT
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON 
SET XACT_ABORT ON  

BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestV1, TestV2, TestV3)
SELECT @v1, @v2, @v3;

-- Begin Return Select <- do not remove
SELECT ID, TestV1, TestV2, TestV3
FROM   dbo.TestTable
WHERE  ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
-- End Return Select <- do not remove

COMMIT TRAN;
GO

-- Example sp to show use of OUTPUT clause
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_InsertSecondMethod
(
    @v1 INT
    ,@v2 INT
    ,@v3 INT
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON 
SET XACT_ABORT ON  

BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestV1, TestV2, TestV3)
OUTPUT INSERTED.*
SELECT @v1, @v2, @v3;

COMMIT TRAN;
GO
```

Both `EXECUTE dbo.usp_InsertFirstMethod 1, 2, 3;` and `EXECUTE dbo.usp_InsertSecondMethod 1, 2, 3;` display the same results. Seems to work!

Comment: Im wondering if i can stop using the scope_ident now..... :-) ( cuz it will be at inserted.*)

Comment: Yeah, you could stop using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` when it's replaced with the `OUTPUT` clause - same results. Nice to know :-)

Comment: No. dont create another cloned table structure. this would make things a lot difficult. you can also use `OUTPUT INSERTED.*` without `into`

Comment: Ahh, you're right, that's a residue of some trying out. I'll edit it out as it is not necessary. Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using `OUTPUT` clause
    DECLARE @@table_variable table(MasterEntityID,...)

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EServices_ME_Country_Info] ([MasterEntityID],...)
OUTPUT inserted.MasterEntityID,...
INTO  @table_variable
SELECT @MasterEntityID, ...
```

And, yes, you can also get all the values that are inserted by default or as IDENTITY.